# copy url to clipboad without using javascript

Tags: html, css

I need to use copy to clipboard function with email templates.Have any way to develop function to copy link to clipboard without using java script?

Comment: For me it's impossible. Javascript have been made for this. Why you are so limited ?

Comment: since when HTML introduced functions?

Answer (score 1):

Only way:

```html
<a href="link.html">Right-click this and choose "copy link address"</a>
```